# next.js where to put file available only from server side scripts

Tags: next.js

From the client I need to consume some api. Those api should read/write from/to a json datasource file. This json must not be available from url. It must be only accessible from filesystem.

This JSON will not contains any environment variables and could be created on the fly programmatically based on users interaction. So it can't be refreshed on rebuild using webpack's EnvironmentPlugin.

This JSON is really simple and using a database seems excessive.

From documentation I can't figure out where to put this datasource file and how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

`Next.js` exposes only the `public` / `statics` folders to be accessible from the internet.

Just create a folder **outside** of these folders, it won't be accessible from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can put your next js file at the root.

Comment: How do you get server.js to run prior to next's root file?